# Do we need the definite article or the indefinite article before something (e.g., a gift) that someone gave us and we thank them for it?

Tags: articles

Which article do I have to use in the following sentence?

> Thank you for **a**/**the** tip.

What if the noun were preceded by an adjective?

> Thank you for **a**/**the** great tip.

Comment: What has happened to your English? :)   Your question is all screwed up (in the box).

Comment: The adjective does not not make a difference.  As Ron Jenson notes in his answer below, you would use the definite article "the" when referring to a specific tip that has been left, or "a" in other circumstances.  The answers are unchanged, whether or not an adjective precedes the noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are referring to a specific tip, use the definite article "the." If, on the other hand, a tip has not been left you would use the indefinite article "a." E.g. *I would appreciate a tip.*

Comment: There are also cases where the indefinite article would apply, even when a tip has been left - e.g. "A generous $100-note tip was left in the jar this afternoon ".

Answer (score 2):

If the tip has been given at a specific time or event:

Thank you for **the tip** [you gave me].

A general statement (which one would probably never see). But for the grammar, one would say/write:

Please don't forget to give our servers **a tip**.

That is a general idea, not specific.